# Should 'composite' classes reference 'parent' class?

Tags: java, hibernate, wicket, parent-child, composition

First time poster, long(ish) time lurker.

I am attempting to develop a simple Project Management program as a learning exercise and trying to learn and follow good programming practices (coding to interfaces, avoiding setters [not entirely sure about this one], using generics) but have a few issues which I've tried to research and solve, but haven't come up with a satisfactory solution, or none which make immediate sense to me.

Eventually it will use Wicket frontend with a Hibernate/JPA/MySQL backend, hence why I'm using Maps rather than Lists (avoids "cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags" error with Hibernate).

At a basic level, I have the following classes:

- Project(Timeboxes, Requirements, ...)
- Timebox(Tasks, ...)
- Requirement(Tasks, ...)
- Task(...)

From anywhere in the chain, I need to know what the parent is and children are. I want to know that a timebox belongs to a certain project, and also has tasks (which are also owned by requirements).

I've written one constructor method,  addRequirement(Requirement,Project), in Project which adds a Requirement to the requirements HashMap as a tentative example of what I currently think is the solution.

1. Should I be putting the Project itself into a Requirement which is associated with it, or just a unique text reference to look up when required?
2. Should I stick with the lack of setters and go with the big constructors and constructor methods, or go with having setters.
3. Should I be worried about the hashCode being limited to integer? And should I make the key for the hashMaps integers rather than Strings?

I've uploaded two of the classes I'm working on, and any constructive criticism would be very helpful :).

Project:
http://pastebin.com/yc1dG8FC

Requirement:
http://pastebin.com/GkPvUZme

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why use maps? A Map is used to index values by keys. It seems that your project has a set of requirements. Why use a map to store them. What would be the key of the map? A setter is useful if some value must be changed after construction. It's pretty unfrequent to know all the requirements of a project when the project is created. Generally, you create a project and then add requirements to the project.

Comment: Also, CascadeType.ALL on a ManyToOne is wrong: you don't want to delete the whole project when deleting a single requirement.

Comment: Sorry, I got the reason why I was using Maps muddled up.
When I initially attempted to use Lists on an earlier experiment, I got "cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags" errors, and one of the solution suggestions was to use a Map instead as they are keyed. I will have methods such as project.addRequirement() as opposed to project.setRequirements() .
Thanks for the CascadeType suggestion.

Comment: You should use Sets instead of Lists then. But this exception shows that you're requesting a cartesian product of two tables: this is often not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

after thinking a while, i think it s good idea provided you use some kind of lazy initialization,

why? because if eager loading the objects you will be querying all the stuff in the hierarchy